# Consuming Kafka using ThreadPool doesn't ensure Ordering?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a `Kafka topic` with `1-partition`. `1 listener` is defined in my spring-boot app using `@KafkaListener`. The `listener` uses a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` which picks the `ConsumerRecord` and processes it. However, I can see the strict ordering that kafka promises doesn't hold, in this scenario, as I can see `offset`s jumping sometimes (verified using timestamp) when parallel Threads starts processing... So questions:

1. Why does the Ordering doesn't follow for parallel threads within
   listener?
2. How can we achieve parallelism and Ordering at the same time, so
   that the parallel thread picks up the next offset and not jump?

**EDIT 1**

```
public class DefaultTopicListener {
    @Autowired
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executorPool;

    @KafkaListener(topicPartitions=@TopicPartition(topic="defaultTopic", 
partitions={"0"}))
    public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, CustomPayload> request) {
        CustomPayload message = request.value();
        try {
            executorPool.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    logger.info(
                            "onMessage : executorPool_THREAD_{}-> -> Offset {}.... ",
                            Thread.currentThread().getId(), request.offset());
                }
            });
        }  catch (RejectedExecutionException ex) {
            logger.error(
                    "onMessage : executorPool -> Queue Full Request Rejected for offset -> {}", ex, );
        }
    }
public class Config {
    @Bean("executorPool")
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executorPool(){
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(3);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(5);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(5);

        return executor;
    }
}
```

Kindly advise.

Answer (score 5):

Kafka typically recommend one thread per consumer. If you want to decouple processing from consumption in that case hands off ConsumerRecords instances to a blocking queue consumed by a pool of processor threads that actually handle the record processing.

https://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html

However ordering in this case is not guaranteed, as the threads will execute independently an earlier chunk of data may actually be processed after a later chunk of data just due to the luck of thread execution timing.

Ordering and Parallelism can be achieved by having multiple partitions and a single thread responsible for the partition, all the records in the partition will be processed in order by the thread.

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear what you mean. Thread pools don't "pick" things, they are given tasks to run. You need to show your code.

Speculating...

If your listener is handing off a `ConsumerRecord` to a thread pool then, of course, record ordering is lost since the records are processed on different threads (unless the pool has a size of 1).

For a single partition, the listener container invokes the listener on a single thread. You must not hand off the work to other threads if you want to retain order.

The only way to achieve concurrency is to use multiple partitions and increase the concurrency on the container. The partitions will be distributed across the container threads.

Or, you need to manage the acknowledgments within your code to make sure no "jumps" are committed.

Ordering is only guaranteed within a partition so, again, you must not hand off to another thread.

Comment: Isn't the Listener supposed to hand-off sequentially to any Thread? Isn't the Listener bound to a Single Consumer which is capable of maintaining the Order and hand-off to sequentially for any processing w/o breaking the offset Ordering? Since I'm maintaining a 1 Partition/1 Listener, my expectation is reading off the Topic has to be ordered.. What am I missing?

Comment: The listener thread polls the consumer and calls the listener one-at-a-time so, yes, it maintains order but if you then hand it off to another thread, order is lost - again - you need to show your code so I can understand better what you are doing. Edit the question to show your code.

Comment: Updated the test case.

Comment: Right - that's what I suspected - you simply can't do that, depending on the container configuration (`AckMode`), the offset will be committed as soon as the message is handed off to the executor (`AckMode.RECORD`), or when the last message from the batch is handed off (`AckMode.BATCH`). You will lose messages (queued in the TaskExecutor) if the server crashes. You could handle it with MANUAL ack mode, but you would have to keep track of the offset so you don't commit an offset where an earlier one has not been processed. In general, it's simply better/easier to use multiple partitions.

Comment: I tried the MANUAL acknowledgement, after handing it over to the ThreadPoolExecutor, so if the threadpool throws exception, the acknowledgement shouldn't be called. But that was not stopping the messages from being delivered to listener even though the exceptions were thrown. So I took the design pointer @asolanki suggested and did few things: 1) Enabled BATCH processing at Consumer side 2) Restricted any message to be delivered to the pool when there are No Active Threads. With these 2 settings the problem is largely controlled. Messages appear Ordered.